# Elasticsearch DSL queries - optional should terms & scores

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-nested

I'm pretty new on Elasticsearch world and I might be missing some concept.

That's the scenario I'm not understanding:

I want to find a doc from the following criteria:

- category.level = A
- category.name = "John .G" OR "Chris T."
- approved = yes (optional)

Mappings:

```
PUT data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "createdAt": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type":   "text",
            "analyzer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "approved": {
        "type":   "text",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
POST data/_create/1
{  
  "category": [
      {
        "name": "John G.",
        "level": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary F.",
        "level": "A"
      }
  ],
  "createdBy": "John",
  "createdAt": "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
  "approved": "yes"
}

POST data/_create/2
{  
  "category": [
      {
        "name": "John G.",
        "level": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chris T.",
        "level": "A"
      }
  ],
  "createdBy": "John",
  "createdAt": "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
  "approved": "no"
}

POST data/_create/3
{  
  "category": [
      {
        "name": "John G.",
        "level": "C"
      },
      {
        "name": "Phil C.",
        "level": "C"
      }
  ],
  "createdBy": "John",
  "createdAt": "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
  "approved": "no"
}

POST data/_create/4
{  
  "category": [
      {
        "name": "John G.",
        "level": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chris T.",
        "level": "A"
      }
  ],
  "createdBy": "John",
  "createdAt": "2020-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
  "approved": "yes"
}

POST data/_create/5
{  
  "category": [
      {
        "name": "Unknown A.",
        "level": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Unknown B.",
        "level": "A"
      }
  ],
  "createdBy": "Unknown",
  "createdAt": "2020-08-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
  "approved": "yes"
}
```

Query:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "category",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"category.level": "A"}}
          ],
          "should": [
            {"term": {"category.name": "John G."}},
            {"term": {"category.name": "Chris T."}},
            {"term": {"approved": "yes"}}
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.4455402,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.4455402,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Chris T.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "no"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.4455402,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Chris T.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2020-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.151647,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Mary F.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "yes"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Why the first document returned is an `approval = no`? I was expecting that docs with `approval = yes` would be better scored.
2. Why doc with index = 5 (it doesn't attend the criteria `category.name`, but it does for `approved = yes`) is not being returned?
3. The optionality of `approved = yes` is not being expressed in the above query. How could I create a kind of extra separated `should` term with `minimum_should_match: 0` ? Something that would increase the score but would not filter the results.

Comment: thanks for posting your question in details and providing all the neccessary input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below query, which have main `bool` query. it have first `must` clause with nested query and it have `bool` query for `category.level` field and then another `bool` query with `should` clause for `category.name` field.

Now main `bool` query have should clause for `approved` which is used for boosting result with `yes` value (this is outside `nested` query).

```json
POST data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "category",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "category.level": {
                        "value": "a"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "category.name": "John G."
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "category.name": "Chris T."
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "approved": "yes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```json
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.9845366,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.9845366,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Chris T.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2020-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.6906434,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Mary F.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.4455402,
        "_source" : {
          "category" : [
            {
              "name" : "John G.",
              "level" : "A"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Chris T.",
              "level" : "A"
            }
          ],
          "createdBy" : "John",
          "createdAt" : "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
          "approved" : "no"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> Why the first document returned is an approval = no? I was expecting
> that docs with approval = yes would be better scored.

Because you have `should` clause inside `nested` query and it is no matching to any document as `approved` is outside `category` hence it is not changing score.

> Why doc with index = 5 (it doesn't attend the criteria category.name,
> but it does for approved = yes) is not being returned?

it is removed by your must clause, but if you need index =5 document as well then you can add two `should` clause, one for nested and one for `approved` and it will resolved your issue.

Your question 3 also resolved by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your scenario with your mapping and sample data, and found the issue, you are using `approved:yes` in the `nested` query context which is causing the issue, which is causing the issue, if you change the query to **below(Basically using `approved:yes` in the should block but outside the `nested` query)**, it solves all your issues.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "category",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "category.level": "A"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "category.name": "John G."
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "category.name": "Chris T."
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "approved": "yes"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71967271",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.9845366,
                "_source": {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "name": "John G.",
                            "level": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Chris T.",
                            "level": "A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdBy": "John",
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
                    "approved": "yes"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71967271",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.4455402,
                "_source": {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "name": "John G.",
                            "level": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Chris T.",
                            "level": "A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdBy": "John",
                    "createdAt": "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
                    "approved": "no"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71967271",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.2437345,
                "_source": {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "name": "John G.",
                            "level": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Mary F.",
                            "level": "A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdBy": "John",
                    "createdAt": "2022-04-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
                    "approved": "yes"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71967271",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 0.7968255,
                "_source": {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "name": "Unknown A.",
                            "level": "A"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Unknown B.",
                            "level": "A"
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdBy": "Unknown",
                    "createdAt": "2020-08-18 19:09:27.527+0200",
                    "approved": "yes"
                }
            }
        ]
```